# Too Many Parameters

Tags: scala, design-patterns

I have an application that has a single EntryPoint, it's a library to automate some data engineers stuffs.

```
case class DeltaContextConfig(
  primaryKey: List[String],
  columnToOrder: String,
  filesCountFirstBatch: Int,
  destinationPath: String,
  sparkDf: DataFrame,
  sparkContext: SparkSession,
  operationType: String,
  partitionColumn: Option[String] = None,
  tableName: String,
  databaseName: String,
  autoCompaction: Option[Boolean] = Option(true),
  idealFileSize: Option[Int] = Option(128),
  deduplicationColumn: Option[String] = None,
  compactionIntervalTime: Option[Int] = Option(180),
  updateCondition: Option[String] = None,
  setExpression: Option[String] = None
)
```

This is my case class, my single Entrypoint.

After that all these parameters are pass to other objects, I have objects to write in Datalake, to Compact files and so on. And these objects use some of these parameters, for example, I have a `DeltaWriterConfig` object:

```
DeltaWriterConfig(
  sparkDf = deltaContextConfig.sparkDf,
  columnToOrder = deltaContextConfig.columnToOrder,
  destinationPath = deltaContextConfig.destinationPath,
  primaryKey = deltaContextConfig.primaryKey,
  filesCountFirstBatch = deltaContextConfig.filesCountFirstBatch,
  sparkContext = deltaContextConfig.sparkContext,
  operationType = deltaContextConfig.operationType,
  partitionColumn = deltaContextConfig.partitionColumn,
  updateCondition = deltaContextConfig.updateCondition,
  setExpression = deltaContextConfig.setExpression
)
```

I use the `DeltaWriterConfig`, to pass these parameters to my class `DeltaWriter`. I was creating all these configs objects on the MAIN, but I think it is not good, because, I have 3 Config Objects to populate, so I have 3 big constructors on the application main.

Is there any pattern to solve this?

Comment: Well... not really. Actually, this is not even really a problem. Its just dependencies for your components.

Answer (score 1):

I think at least it would be better to replace creating another config from the first one to the companion object of `DeltaWriterConfig`:

```
case class DeltaWriterConfig(
                              sparkDf: DataFrame,
                              columnToOrder: String,
                              destinationPath: String,
                              primaryKey: List[String],
                              filesCountFirstBatch: Int,
                              sparkContext: SparkSession,
                              operationType: String,
                              partitionColumn: Option[String] = None,
                              updateCondition: Option[String] = None,
                              setExpression: Option[String] = None
                            )
case object DeltaWriterConfig {
  def from(deltaContextConfig: DeltaContextConfig): DeltaWriterConfig =
    DeltaWriterConfig(
      sparkDf = deltaContextConfig.sparkDf,
      columnToOrder = deltaContextConfig.columnToOrder,
      destinationPath = deltaContextConfig.destinationPath,
      primaryKey = deltaContextConfig.primaryKey,
      filesCountFirstBatch = deltaContextConfig.filesCountFirstBatch,
      sparkContext = deltaContextConfig.sparkContext,
      operationType = deltaContextConfig.operationType,
      partitionColumn = deltaContextConfig.partitionColumn,
      updateCondition = deltaContextConfig.updateCondition,
      setExpression = deltaContextConfig.setExpression
    )
}
```

it gives us opportunity to create new config just in one line:

```
val deltaContextConfig: DeltaContextConfig = ???
val deltaWriterConfig = DeltaWriterConfig.from(deltaContextConfig)
```

but the better solution is have only that configs that are unique. For example if we have duplicates fields in `DeltaContextConfig` and `DeltaWriterConfig` why we couldn't have just composition of config and not duplicate these fields:

```
// instead of this DeltaContextConfig declaration
case class DeltaContextConfig(
                               tableName: String,
                               databaseName: String,
                               autoCompaction: Option[Boolean] = Option(true),
                               idealFileSize: Option[Int] = Option(128),
                               deduplicationColumn: Option[String] = None,
                               compactionIntervalTime: Option[Int] = Option(180),

                               sparkDf: DataFrame,
                               columnToOrder: String,
                               destinationPath: String,
                               primaryKey: List[String],
                               filesCountFirstBatch: Int,
                               sparkContext: SparkSession,
                               operationType: String,
                               partitionColumn: Option[String] = None,
                               updateCondition: Option[String] = None,
                               setExpression: Option[String] = None
                             )

case class DeltaWriterConfig(
                              sparkDf: DataFrame,
                              columnToOrder: String,
                              destinationPath: String,
                              primaryKey: List[String],
                              filesCountFirstBatch: Int,
                              sparkContext: SparkSession,
                              operationType: String,
                              partitionColumn: Option[String] = None,
                              updateCondition: Option[String] = None,
                              setExpression: Option[String] = None
                            )
```

we use such config structure:

```
case class DeltaContextConfig(
                               tableName: String,
                               databaseName: String,
                               autoCompaction: Option[Boolean] = Option(true),
                               idealFileSize: Option[Int] = Option(128),
                               deduplicationColumn: Option[String] = None,
                               compactionIntervalTime: Option[Int] = Option(180),
                               deltaWriterConfig: DeltaWriterConfig
                             )

case class DeltaWriterConfig(
                              sparkDf: DataFrame,
                              columnToOrder: String,
                              destinationPath: String,
                              primaryKey: List[String],
                              filesCountFirstBatch: Int,
                              sparkContext: SparkSession,
                              operationType: String,
                              partitionColumn: Option[String] = None,
                              updateCondition: Option[String] = None,
                              setExpression: Option[String] = None
                            )
```

but remember you should use the same config structure in your config file.